# post xml data to rest api in MVC application

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have a rest api service which takes xml as input and returns json as output with basic authorization. How do I consume this api in a mvc application.

Comment: Xml as input and json as output?

Comment: The same way you always consume json? What is the issue?

Comment: I need a sample code to start with.